# Trends in the melting points of alcohols, aldehydes and ketones

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, alcohols, melting-point

Is there a general trend in the melting points of alcohols, aldehydes and ketones? Usually with the boiling point, it increases as the number of hydrocarbons increase, but what happens in the case of melting point?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry StackExchange. Normally its best to try find the answer yourself first then ask a question based on this data that you still find puzzling.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the trend in both melting and boiling point somewhat remain same. But the trend may alter due to reasons like hydrogen bonding, symmetrical structure leading to better packing in crystal lattice, increased stability due to some reasons, structure, etc.